# OpenCV import does not compile in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, opencv

I included `OpenCV` in my `Xcode` project as given [here](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/#using).

Then I declare an openCV Matrix object `cv::Mat` in my header file.

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController 
{
   cv::Mat myMat;

}
```

When I try to compile this fails with error, "`Type name requires a specifier or qualifier`"

The same problem does not happen when I locally declare a `cv::Mat` object in my `.mm` files. Also, a sample project I have has the same `cv::Mat` objects declared in its header files, and that project compiles.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you #include the opencv headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was solved when i changed the source file-name extension to `.mm`.